# Prevent Facebook from scraping specific images when somebody shares a link to my page

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to prevent Facebook from using specific images when a user shares a link to a page on my site?

My site has user-generated content and while I include proper `og:image` tags for images the user uploads and which are part of his/her article, sometimes no image is uploaded or the image uploaded does not meet Facebook's quality requirements. In that case, Facebook will pick other images it finds on the page and those other images can be from a "Related articles" section or images not content-related at all. It would be nice if I could flag these images in such a way that Facebook ignores them.

Comment: try reading the documentation of the Facebook open graph protocol. You might find some related information.

Comment: There is no mechanism to do any “flagging” of this kind. This is something your system should handle, by explicitly specifying a dummy image then, if none was uploaded, or the specified one is too small (I think that is the main restriction when it comes to Facebook’s requirements.)

Comment: Right, my problem was with images that are too small. The current limitation is 200x200 I think and I have some users that post images that are smaller. I could implement dummy images, but if Facebook decides to change the requirement to 500x500 tomorrow, my logic is broken and no dummy image is sent.